# resources.ApplyResources() causes ambiguous match error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, resources, ambiguous

Ok, so I work in a company with multiple developers using VS2013 linked by TFS. When I run our application, it runs fine until I open a certain window. When this form loads, it hits a line in the designer of the form:

```
    resources.ApplyResources(Me.tcPersonnel, "tcPersonnel") 'tcPersonnel being a tabcontrol
```

When it hits this line, I get an error saying there is an "Ambiguous match is found". If I continue anyway (ignoring the error), the form and that control works fine.

The weird part is that when my colleagues map my branch to their computers and get the latest version (my stuff all being checked in), and run it, it works without any errors. This to me points to that there may be something wrong with my computer rather than bad code.

The relevant Resx elements are below:

```
    <data name="&gt;&gt;tcPersonnel.Name" xml:space="preserve">
      <value>tcPersonnel</value>
    </data>
    <data name="&gt;&gt;tcPersonnel.Type" xml:space="preserve">
      <value>System.Windows.Forms.TabControl, System.Windows.Forms, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</value>
    </data>
    <data name="&gt;&gt;tcPersonnel.Parent" xml:space="preserve">
      <value>tlpCentral</value>
    </data>
    <data name="&gt;&gt;tcPersonnel.ZOrder" xml:space="preserve">
      <value>1</value>
    </data>
```

Is there a solution to this as all my research has come back with nothing.

P.S. My machine is the only one out of all my colleagues that is running a 64bit operating system, not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: That's not pretty.  At least show us the element in the .resx file that contains the resources for tcPersonnel.

Comment: Using .NET 1.0 on a 64-bit machine is a bit like a dinosaur-and-humans movie.  No idea what could possibly go wrong, unlikely you have 1.0 installed.  Time to move up.  Give *everybody* a 64-bit machine, those dinosaurs need to go as well, move to .NET 4 asap.

Comment: We are currently on .Net 3.5, and this problem has only just started today.

Comment: Aha! So what changed yesterday/today:

Comment: Nothing, we did one merge around but that's it... no windows updates, no updates to visual studio

Answer (score 0):

This usually indicates one or more files in your TFS workspace have got out of sync with TFS.

To resolve it, instead of using the normal Get Latest, you can force a get of the latest files without allowing TFS to skip files it thinks are up to date.

(Apologies for the 2010 screenshots, I'll try and update them for 2013 when I'm on a 2013 box later today, but you should find the equivalent functionality in 2013.)

In Source Control Explorer, right-click your project and choose Get Specific Version:

[image]

And in the next dialog, choose Latest Version and select both checkboxes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried what you have explained, and sadly it did not work. I don't know if it makes any difference but I am the only machine that is running a 64bit operating system, would that make a difference?